# Make intellisense recognize enums in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, binding

So I have the following setup:

Firstly, I use a custom Binding to handle localized strings like so:

```
/// <summary>
/// Handles XAML Bindings to localized strings.
/// </summary>    
public class LocalizedExtension : Binding
{        
    public LocalizedExtension(Defs name)
                : base("[" + name.ToString() + "]")
    {
        this.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
        this.Source = TranslationSource.Instance;
    }
}
```

`Defs` is an enumeration of all possible translation-keys. For example `Defs.pane` would be the translation of "Pane" in German, English and so on.

In XAML one would use this binding like so:

```
<CheckBox
      x:Name="checkA"
      Content="{loc:Localized pane,
                        TargetNullValue='LSG'}" />
```

Is there a way to have the argument for the binding ("pane") chosen from the enum? So I get the **proposals from IntelliSense** for the keys instead of having to write the exact string?

Comment: with visual studio you can't. it's possible with resharper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `{x:Static}` markup extension:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="checkA"
          Content="{loc:Localized {x:Static Defs.Pane},
                    TargetNullValue='LSG'}" />
```

This markup is used to reference constants, static properties, fields and enumeration values. Since it requires strong or explicit types, you will get Intellisense support.

Comment: That works fine. Although I have to explicitly supply a namespace: `loc:Defs.Pane`

Comment: I'm happy I could help. You always have to qualify a type with its namespace. Build-in types e.g. `ListView` are the exception. Also when importing a namespace with `using` types are automatically resolved. You generally have to tell the compiler the exact type (fully qualified).